# Importing AlpineJS via (inline) script module

Tags: javascript, module, alpine.js

Since I wanted to add some modules to Alpine JS, I tried to load Alpine via script module as descriped in the [documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#registering-from-a-bundle). However, somehow I must have misunderstood something or made a mistake, since it does not work.

**Notes:**

1. I downloaded the [script](https://unpkg.com/alpinejs) and saved it accordingly in
   `modules/alpine.js`
2. I use *Visual Studio Code* and run the preview using the *Live Preview* extension from Microsoft
3. With the import path used below I get this 404 error: *GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/modules/alpine net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)*
4. When I change the import path of AlpineJS to `./modules/alpine.js` I get the the following error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './modules/alpine.js' does not provide an export named 'default'*

```html
<!-- <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script> This would work -->
<script type="module"><!-- This does NOT work -->
    import Alpine from './modules/alpine';
    Alpine.start();
</script>

<div x-data="{ test: 'hello world' }">
    <span x-text="test"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to import Alpine.js as a module, you have to import from the module build, not from the CDN build.

Install Alpine.js with a package manager:

```
npm install alpinejs
```

Then you can import Alpine.js as a module from `./node_modules`:

```
<script type="module">
    import Alpine from './node_modules/alpinejs/dist/module.esm'
    Alpine.start()
</script>
```

If you wish you can also copy `module.esm` to a different directory and delete `node_modules`.

Comment: Thank you! Can I do this without a package manager? I want to keep it simple by not getting into using one...

Comment: I think you need to rename `.esm` to `.js` in order for it to work such that the MIME type is as the browser expects it

Comment: Yes, you can download the script file directly from [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alpinejs/v/3.12.0?activeTab=explore) as well.